# How to access restless services through firefox addon

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox-addon

I have been trying for a while to access a restless interface within a firefox addon. After reading in a bunch of places I came accross getJASONP jquery function that gets around the cross-origin resource sharing problem but it feels like a hack. Isn't there a more elegant way of getting get and post data with jquery through a firefox plug in. I would be really surprised if a hack was the only way.

thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //var url = "http://132.205.237.32:8182/services";
        var url ="http://127.0.0.1/learning.php";
      $.getJSON(url+'?callback=?', {type:"json"}, function (results) {
          alert(results.service1);
     });
    });
```

Comment: Firefox add-ons aren't bound by same-origin policy, so you must be doing something wrong. But your question doesn't provide any details on what you are attempting to do so impossible to tell more.

Comment: I have added the code that uses jsonp. Are you saying if I rewrite the code using a regular post call it should work as long as it's within a firefox plugin?

Comment: Yes, a regular `XMLHttpRequest` (either directly or via jQuery wrappers) should always work in a Firefox extension. JSONP on the other hand is always a security vulnerability if used in a Firefox extension (you are running code from the web with extension privileges), don't do that.

Comment: Cool thanks can you put that as an answer so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just access them - e.g. using `XMLHttpRequest`. Firefox extensions aren't bound by same-origin policy and are allowed to request any address from the web.

A side-note: Please never use JSONP in a Firefox extension, it's a security vulnerability. By using JSONP you are running some code from the web with the privileges of your extension.